# Background image is not coming with the ion-list view in ionic 2 application

Tags: css, ionic2, background-image

i am trying to set an background image in ionic 2 application, but the background image is not setting behind the list. Is there any way to get the image to cover the full screen with the list view as well?

Screenshot:

[image]

My code:

```css
.backgound-image {
  background-image: url('../img/Grammar.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
```

```html
<ion-content class="backgound-image">
 
  <ion-title></ion-title> 
  <ion-list>
  <ion-item>    
    <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
   <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
   <br>
  <ion-item style="text-align:center;">
  
  <button style="border-radius: 0px!Important; width: 70%!Important;" ion-button color="primary" (click)="dashboardPage()">Login</button><br><br>
  <p style="text-align: center;color: blue;">Forgot password?</p><hr>
 <p style="text-align: center; display: inline ">not a member? </p><p style="text-align: center;color: blue; display: inline"> Sign up here</p>
  </ion-item>
  </ion-list> 
  
  <div class="hr-sect">Or Login with</div>
  
  <ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
  <button style="border-radius: 0px!Important; width: 70%!Important; margin-left: 15%;" ion-button block color="danger">Google+</button>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
  <button style="border-radius: 0px!Important; width: 70%!Important; margin-left: 15%;" ion-button block color="button">facebook</button>
  </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
 
  
  <ion-footer style="margin:0rem 0rem!Important;">
  <button ion-button block color="Dark" (click)="pushPage()">Explore</button>
  </ion-footer>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: did you try setting transparent background to ion-list?

Comment: you can  add it as an answer and accept it.. Will help others with similar issues

Answer (score 1):

Set background size property cover like below:

```css
 .backgound-image {
  background-image: url('../img/Grammar.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks got the answer.

```css
ion-item{
  background: transparent !important;
}
```